# My computer takes like 5 minutes to start, but it wasn't like this before

Tags: windows, windows-11

My computer used to start up in like 10 seconds and it was perfectly fine, but one day it just decided to take super long and it still is today.

I know this isn't my startup apps as most of them are disabled, so I don't know what's causing it.

Specifications:

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4310M CPU @ 2.70GHz
- 8GB DDR3 Ram
- SSD 128GB
- Intel HD Graphics 4600
- American Metagrands BIOS

---

```
WARNING!  /F parameter not specified.
Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  802560 file records processed.
File verification completed.
 Phase duration (File record verification): 18.88 seconds.
  34947 large file records processed.
 Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 50.06 milliseconds.
  0 bad file records processed.
 Phase duration (Bad file record checking): 0.56 milliseconds.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  48460 reparse records processed.
  1067094 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
 Phase duration (Index verification): 55.28 seconds.
  0 unindexed files scanned.
 Phase duration (Orphan reconnection): 18.00 seconds.
  0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.
 Phase duration (Orphan recovery to lost and found): 0.64 milliseconds.
  48460 reparse records processed.
 Phase duration (Reparse point and Object ID verification): 275.06 milliseconds.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.
 Phase duration (Security descriptor verification): 147.94 milliseconds.
  132268 data files processed.
 Phase duration (Data attribute verification): 4.58 milliseconds.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  37203184 USN bytes processed.
Usn Journal verification completed.
 Phase duration (USN journal verification): 228.33 milliseconds.

Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.

 124272639 KB total disk space.
  96451460 KB in 507200 files.
    329396 KB in 132269 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    927703 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
  26564080 KB available on disk.

   4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
  31068159 total allocation units on disk.
   6641020 allocation units available on disk.
Total duration: 1.54 minutes (92905 ms).
```

This is what was returned.

When running CrystalDiskInfo, the health of my disk is at 93%. Writes are around 10717GB

Diagnostic Startup doesn't help either.

Comment: Run `chkdsk` and also check the SMART attributes of the disk (post them in your post if you need advice).

Comment: I'll try this after class